# Request a url using IP address of specific country in python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a script which tests a tracking URL is reachable to the app on the app store or not.

For this, I need to get the IP address of country in question and using that IP I need to request the tracking URL. So it will be like request went through that country and we will come to know if URL is reachable to the app store for that country or not.

**Question: How do I request the URL as if its requested from IP I provide?**

Example:

```
def check_url_is_valid(url, ip_address):
    # Trying to request url using ip_address
    # return True or False
```

PS: Not expecting to complete this code but any direction or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get a "country's IP address" since there is no such thing. There are ranges of IP addresses corresponding to different ISP's in different locations. You should pass each request through a proxy that you know is located where you want it to be.

For that you will need to create your own proxy list for each country and pass your requests through proxy every time for each country. You should explore some possible free or payed proxies for that.

Anyway, once you do, sending a request through a proxy can be done like this:

```
proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : "http://1.1.1.1:123", 
              "https" : "https://1.1.1.1:456", 
              "ftp"   : "ftp://1.1.1.1:789"
            }

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxyDict)
```

Of course you should replace the fake addresses above with real proxies that are good for what you want.

By the way, i'm sure there are off the shelf solutions for that, so maybe you should seek them out first instead of "reinventing the wheel". For example: https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. So for each country, I need to pass IP address dict right? We are trying to use 3rd party service which will give us IP address pool for each country.

Comment: correct. but 3rd party service would be your best option

Comment: Thanks do you know any service for it ?

Comment: There's a link at the end of my answer to one such service

Comment: I dont want to test availability of website. I want to test if urls leads to playstore or app store. For that I need IP proxying and User agent string manipulation stuffs.

Comment: I lack knowledge in that and can't help you further, apologies

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 3rd party service which manually checks the URL by country/region, e.g. [asm.ca.com](https://asm.ca.com/en/ping.php) I guess there's no way you can do it for specific IP. So you should determine the country by IP first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use web proxies that allow hotlinking or APIs, or you can use proxychains if you are on linux, or if you want to go for manual effort go for VPNs.